# What design pattern does this follow?

Tags: security, design-patterns

In my web app, I require users to re-enter their password after five minutes of inactivity, similar to how sudo works on Linux. Their password is used to decrypt information.

FWIW, the app is heavily Javascript and AJAX-driven, just like a desktop app, using ExtJS.

So, I've built a class which provides access to a decryption key based on the password they enter. This class expires the key after five minutes.

My question is: **what design pattern does this follow** or **what would be a better name than 'Sentry'?** I'm trying to name my class appropriately. Here's the class thus far:

```
class SecureResourceSentry
  include Singleton

  def initialize
    # Set a default number of seconds for access to expire.
    set_access_expiration_interval(300)

    @key = nil
    @time_last_accessed = 0
  end

  def set_access_expiration_interval(seconds)
    @access_expiration_interval = seconds
  end

  def set_raw_key(raw_key)
    @key = Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(raw_key)
  end

  def getKey
    if @key.nil?
      raise SecureResourceError, 'No key has been set.'
    end

    if access_is_expired
      @key = nil
      raise SecureResourceError, 'Access has expired.'
    end

    return @key
  end

  private
    def access_is_expired
      return Time.now.to_i - @time_last_accessed > @access_expiration_interval
    end
end
```

Comment: it doesn't... [Design Patterns : Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_(computer_science)) ... i know wikipedia is not the be all of documenting this stuff, but you have already assigned it as a Singleton when you included that in there, but it still is not a Singleton.  You design pattern is you create a one off class instance that doesn't really have a pattern.

You have put into practice and great security technique!

Comment: I don't know what design pattern this follows, but I am pretty sure you are mixing concerns here. Access to the key could possibly be guarded using either the decorator or the proxy pattern and it would allow you not to mix different concerns in the same class.

Comment: How is this thing a singleton?  I agree with Martin.

Comment: @Chris @Martin I need to store a single key that persists through the user's session, and I need behavior to expire the key. The key is used by multiple models throughout the application. Where else could I store this key and behavior besides a singleton?

Comment: @Chad: You can pass references to your objects in constructors of objects that need them (Dependency injection). This is a really good read about singletons: http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/25/root-cause-of-singletons/

Comment: @Chad: The expiration behavior is something that should be decoupled from the key. Currently, your expiration behavior is based on time, but what if in the future, expirations are managed by a remote key server/web service or based on a number of use or whatever ? You would have to modify working code. Decoupling it (Decorator Pattern) allow for more flexibility and easier to maintain code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks similar to the revocable accessor described in this secure design patterns talk : ["The Lazy Programmer's Guide to Secure Computing"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eL5o4PFuxTY)

Maybe call it an expiring accessor.

Comment: Thanks, I'm calling it SecureResourceAccessor.